# How to display a JSON file in a webgrid without uploading it to the database using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, upload, webgrid

Im currently working on a project where I want to upload a file(not really upload but select by upload function) and display the data of this file in a webgrid in my view. What I got so far:

My View to upload a JSON file:

[image]

After uploading I'm extracting the keys of this JSON file:

[image]

This data I want to display in a WebGrid in my view without uploading it to the database, does anyone know how to do this?

View code so far:

```
@model List<APIBrokerFrontend.Models.JsonModel>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Api Broker";
if (Session["userID"] == null)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Login/Index");
}
var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10);
grid.Bind(source: Model, rowCount: ViewBag.TotalRows, autoSortAndPage: false);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <h2>API Broker</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="content1">
        <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
        </div>
        <!--Search field and button-->
        <div class="col-sm-5 d-flex align-items-stretch" style="padding-top: 5%;">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Import", "Mapper", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 12%;">
                    <p>JSON File: <input type="file" name="jsonFile" /></p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Import" />
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="content2">
            <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                @grid.Table(tableStyle: "table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                  grid.Column(columnName: "Key", header: "Keys", format:@<text><div class="" data-id="@item.Key" data-propertyname="Key">@item.Key</div></text>)
            )
        )
            </div>
            <!--Pagerlist for webgrid-->
            <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                @grid.PagerList(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, paginationStyle: "pagination pagination-small pagination-right")
            </div>

            @Html.Hidden("dir", grid.SortDirection)
            @Html.Hidden("col", grid.SortColumn)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller code:

```
public class MapperController : Controller
{
    // GET: Mapper
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase jsonFile)
    {
        if (!Path.GetFileName(jsonFile.FileName).EndsWith(".json"))
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "No JSON file";
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            List<string> jsonData = new List<string>();
            using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(jsonFile.InputStream))
            {

                using (JsonTextReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
                {
                    JObject o2 = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(jsonReader);
                    List<string> keys = o2.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
                    var data = keys;
                    return View(keys);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope somebody can help,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have a look at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how transient you want the data to be. If you are not uploading it to any form of storage, I assume its a very short term use.
Hence, what you can do is to cache the data or easier still is to store the data as json in a **TempData** object which you can then retrieve from same TempData object to use in the same or another MVC page.

In addition, if you choose to store it as json, you can always parse it back to an object type using NewtonSoft.
Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: It's for short term use to configure something, im trying to upload 2 json files, extract the keys from this JSON file and link them with eachother by webgrid configuration. However I cant even display the keys of one json file in a webgrid right now.